# How to fill nulls on Spark with a "when" statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, null

How can i fill nulls of a column when the value of another columns is less tha a number?

for example,

```
val filledage = age.na.fill(30,Array("Age")) ..... when kidscolumns>1
```

something like that

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a `dataframe` as

```
+----+-------+
|Age |column1|
+----+-------+
|null|6      |
|null|20     |
|35  |10     |
|25  |5      |
+----+-------+
```

and you want to replace `null` values in `Age` column with `30` when `column1` value is less than `15`, then you can do

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val comparingValue = 15
df.withColumn("Age", when(col("column1")<comparingValue, lit(30)))
```

which should give you

```
+----+-------+
|Age |column1|
+----+-------+
|30  |6      |
|null|20     |
|30  |10     |
|30  |5      |
+----+-------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: This is great ! One question more , how can I fill only the nulls ? Is that possible ?

Comment: @BillyBonaros, if the answer helped you , please accept the answer. :)